# IE 11 Compatibility made checkbox slow

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, internet-explorer

Problem:

I have an issue when my IE 11 compatibility mode is on, when i tick on the checkbox in jsp, it is very very slow, when i try it with compatibility mode off, it works pretty fine, I am not sure why. I am using javascript, html and jsp.

Details:

The logic when I press on the checkbox as following:

1) First upon loading screen I will pull the data from db and display it on screen(around 8k records, only do it 1 time).

In the screen I will show these 3 columns and data being pulled from db when load the screen, checked column has the checkbox. By default I will set checkbox value as N, so when I load the screen, it will uncheck the checkbox.

### ID Number | Name | Checked

Query:

```
   SELECT ID, Name, ('N') CHECKED FROM TableA
```

2) Then I am using while loop to iterate through the records.

```
<%     
  Iterator iter = null;
  iter = vctList.iterator();
  int i = 0;
  while (iter.hasNext())
  {
    i++;  
    str = (String [])iter.next(); 
%>
    <TR>
       <TD><input type="text" name="ID_<%=i%>"  value="<%=str[0]%>" ></TD>
       <TD><input type="text" name="Name_<%=i%>" value="str[1])%>"></TD>  
       <TD align="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_<%=i%>" <%=str[2] != null && str[2].equals("Y"))?"checked":""%> </TD> 
    </TR>
 <% 
  }
 %>
```